# How do I forcefully override my ISP's DNS on my router config?

Tags: router, dns, isp

A new ISP arrived at my city, offering much better plans and I hired their service.
The problem I'm having now is that I want to filter content using openDNS (to block adult content), but it does nothing when I configure the router to use openDNS. I even changed routers, bit still the change to openDNS is not effective. I also changed the windows configuration of one of my computer's to use openDNS, but it takes no effect.
It's also strange that after I clear my router's configuration and insert openDNS instead of the old one, when I check my connection status it will show me 3 DNS server addresses, two that I have provided and a third one, which I presume is the same as the one the technician had configured when he first installed the cables. Now, even if I purge that address, it still shows up there later.

Ps: I use the same router I had when on my old ISP, the change would take place in an instant back then. I'd configure the new DNS server, reset the connection, and then all adult content would be blocked, showing openDNS' page instead.
Now, even when I check http://welcome.opendns.com it shows me I'm not using it.

Comment: So, just to make sure. After setting up OpenDNS in Windows, when you open `nslookup`, you should see `208.67.222.123` or `208.67.202.123` as the DNS server. When you type in `welcome.opendns.com` it should resolve to `146.112.59.8`. Is this really not working?

Comment: Ah, depending on which OpenDNS product you’re using you might see different addresses. Just make sure it’s one of the two you configured.

Comment: Did the technician install any software on your computer? Also, is the additional dns ip "different". Like if your OpenDNS ips are `208.67.222.123` and `208.67.202.123` is the third IP something odd like `2001:FFF:1234::1`? And have you flushed your dns cache and restarted?

Comment: @DanielB I formatted the computer last week, don't know what happened but now entenring http://welcome.opendns.com shows me I'm using open dns. `nslookup` also gives me the said results you pointed out, but STILL the adult content is not being filtered, even after flushing the dns and restarting the pc, as @CliffArmstrong pointed out :(

Comment: @CliffArmstrong AFAIK he didn't install anything. I had to format the computer last week and now I was able to enter use opendns, as I said in the above comment, but content is not being filtered. I don't have a linux machine around to test, but in android, I still can't override the ISP's dns (I use an app called DNS override to do it).
And yes, the third dns I see in my router is the ISP's DNS (it's the one the technician had set on my router before, it's it's an ipv4 address though).
I don't know  what's happening but someone told me I need a dd-wrt router with dnsmasq to solve this.

Comment: Well reinstalling the OS pretty well eliminates software issues. And I don't think dd-wrt is going to solve your problem. It might let you work around it by doing content filtering yourself... but that's not really fixing the issue. You could try removing the ISPs DNS from your router. But it's possibly they are hijacking your dns traffic. If that's the case you would need to switch to using [DNSCrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/).

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I'll take a look into this DNSCrypt thing later. I also already tried different ways of removing their DNS from my router (manually, I already removed it, also reset the router/changed router, still no effect). In the end, I just have to thank you for the help, I'm glad I could get some valuable help.

Comment: Sounds like the router is still acquiring its DNS servers via DHCP. Unfortunately, you probably need DHCP for your internet IP. And not all routers allow you to disable DHCP for DNS addesses and keep it on for IP addresses. This is something I'm confident DD-WRT _would_ allow you to do. So there's that. But simply using DNSCrypt might be the easier option. And you're welcome. I hope you find a solution.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Hi cliff, sorry for getting back to you so long afterwards.

Using DNSCrypt did solve my problem back then, would you like to elaborate an answer so that I can approve it?

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the OP question, but I got here from Google and there's no answer, so I'll write what worked for me.

In my router interface, I found that there is an option saying **ISP DNS, and I switched that to Off** and it allowed me to write the OpenDNS servers.

Having this option, the welcome.opendns.com page worked fine, but the filters still weren't, so adult content was accessible.

I found out that my public IP resolved to IPv6, but **OpenDNS does not support IPv6**.

So, I searched and found another option in my router to **disable IPv6**, and after that it started working for me.

Comment: I think OpenDNS does support IPv6.
Check it out: https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/ipv6/

Comment: It seems that you are right. However, this was the only solution that worked for me, after many attempts. At the time of my post I found an article that was saying that OpenDNS does not support IPv6. Perhaps it was older, but it worked for me...